# Why do I get "IMS Service Has Stopped" Message after update

Tags: updates, sms, 5.1-lollipop

I've got an Galaxy S5 neo with Android version 5.1.1. and a recent Android software update has brought with it an annoying popup message that reappears 3 seconds after being dismissed.

It reads:

> Unfortunately, IMS Service has stopped

I've hunted around for suggestions which range from device cache clearance, to uninstalling Facebook Messanger/WahtsApp to taking the battery out, but none of these has helped.

Short of a factory reset which I'm very reluctant to do, is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

Settings → Applications → Default Applications and I set the Messages from Messages to Client, this stopped the pop ups.

Further to this having set Messages to Client I then found out the offending app was myMail, which I uninstalled and was able to set Messages back from Client to Messages

Hope it helps.

The Client is the default message service of Android I believe and the Messages is Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo's own software, I could be wrong, I'm not an expert, I just know how I fixed mine. So following the above, this Client app should be available. Beyond that I'm sorry, I cannot help.

Comment: Further to this having set Messages to Client I then found out the offending app was myMail, which I uninstalled and was able to set Messages back from Client to Messages.

Comment: I don't get a Client option, just 'Messages' and 'Hangouts' . 'Messages' is the selected option

Answer (score 1):

Try choosing any one of the other options that you CAN see. The pop ups should stop. Then change back to Messages. The pop ups should not return.

Comment: Sorry. The pops up returned after continued use of Messages app. Looks like we will have to choose another default app permanently.

Answer (score 1):

I have a S5 Neo. Try this, it works — I just did it 5 minutes ago.

- Click into messages
- Click more
- Choose settings
- Choose chat settings
- Then rich communications
- Uncheck rich communications

You just won't be able to send large files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was driving me mad. So I did as [Geoff's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/135555/1465) suggests, but there was no Client option so I changed it to a Call+ & Message+ and it seems to have worked.